# What is the purpose of `Build branch filters` in Continuous deployment trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

A build pipeline can be tied to only 1 source branch.

In release pipeline, we configure an artifact by selecting the source build pipeline. So a release artifact can be tied to only 1 build pipeline.

What is the purpose of `Build branch filters` in Continuous deployment trigger?

Comment: Your opening premise is flawed. *A build pipeline can be tied to only 1 source branch* is an incorrect statement **unless** you're talking about TFVC. Are you using TFVC?

Comment: On my build pipeline, under GET SOURCES, I have selected azure repos git and selected the repo name and branch name. Does that answer your question?

Comment: That's the *default* branch. Depending on what you define as triggers, the build will run on the triggering branch. When queuing a build, you can choose any branch you want.

Comment: Ok thanks I was under a wrong impression that - irrespective of which branch is selected in trigger,  always the code from default branch is used by build pipeline. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @DanielMann - I have enabled 'continuous deployment trigger' (not added any branch filter) and disabled 'Pull request trigger'. Now when I raise PR, then the PR triggers a build (since I have build validation configured). Once build completes, it triggers a release. Why does this happen when I have the "pull request trigger" disabled? The triggering of release prior to PR approval is prevented only when I add a branch filter to the "continuous deployment trigger".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say that your code base was updated. You want deploy only if build was made over specific branch (example `develop`).

In that scenario `Build Branch Filter` looks fairly redundant... but what if:

1. You want to trigger new deployment for every `latest` artifact, built from `each` feature branch to get them tested. You have to filter for `feature/*`.
2. You want to trigger new deployments if your release branches are updated, but some of them are deprecated and you need to filter them out. I that scenario specify one `include` filter `release/*` and second `exclude` filter `release/old*`.

Anyway.. in most of the cases the filter and the branch name (in artifact) will match each other. Still sometimes it can be heady to trigger deployment from multiple branches or filter something out.

---

*In regards to your comment, I uploaded part of the `yaml build`. In fact one build can create artifacts from all branches in repository if you want.*

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - feature/*
    - bugfix/*
    - release/*
    - develop
    - master
    exclude:
    - experimental/*
```

Comment: 1 release artifact can be tied to only 1 build pipeline. Build pipeline can be tied to only 1 source branch. So what is the purpose of branch filter

Comment: Why? Build pipeline can be triggered from many branches, here you have a part of yaml build definition. 

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - feature/*
    - bugfix/*
    - release/*
    - develop
    - master
    exclude:
    - experimental/*
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also help with this: In release pipeline build artifact I have enabled 'continuous deployment trigger' (not added any branch filter) and disabled 'Pull request trigger'. Now when I raise PR, then the PR triggers a build (since I have build validation configured). Once build completes, it triggers a release. Why does this happen when I have the "pull request trigger" disabled?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you don't want release pipeline triggered after the build from `pull request branch` is completed. Could you please share information how the triggers in release pipeline look?

Comment: The release pipeline has 1 build artifact with continuous deployment trigger enabled and pull request trigger disabled.

Comment: Continuous deployment trigger creates a release every time a new build is available. You say `Now when I raise PR, then the PR triggers a build` in that case build was created and release will be triggered. Pull request trigger allows you to filter only builds coming from PR's. It is useful if you want a pipeline only for testing PR's.